# "Зато" - общее для двух предложений в ССП?

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

> Зато очевидно по размаху городского строительства, что основатель
>   династии Флавиев (69–96), скромный по своему происхождению полководец
>   Веспасиан был весьма заинтересован в расположении к нему народных
>   масс, и развёрнутое им грандиозное общественное строительство тому
>   доказательством.

После Веспасиана уточнение закрывается?

Перед "и развёрнутое" на месте ль зпт? - это я её влепила...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Зато очевидно по размаху городского строительства, что основатель династии Флавиев (69–96)***, скромный по своему происхождению полководец Веспасиан,*** был весьма заинтересован в расположении к нему народных масс.

---

Стоит закрыть запятой. Я бы оборот с Веспасиан интерпретировал как распространённое обособленное приложение.

Вот Розенталь пишет:  «Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если служит для пояснения или уточнения нарицательного существительного. Перед перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова "а зовут его", "а именно", "то есть"».

Пример: *«Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться»* (Тургенев).

Ваше предложение: *«Основатель династии Флавиев (69–96), скромный по своему происхождению полководец Веспасиан, был весьма заинтересован в расположении к нему народных масс».*

Как видно, этот тургеневский пример абсолютно идентичен по структуре вашему предложению.

Определяемое слово в качестве подлежащего (,)приложение(,) сказуемое.

---

Второй ваш вопрос неоднозначен.

> Зато очевидно по размаху городского строительства, что основатель
>   династии Флавиев (69–96), скромный по своему происхождению полководец
>   Веспасиан, был весьма заинтересован в расположении к нему народных
>   масс(,) и развёрнутое им грандиозное общественное строительство тому
>   доказательством.

Поначалу хочется предположить, что это вроде как однородные придаточные предложения с присловной зависимостью, поясняющие слово "очевидно". А раз так, то и запятая перед союзом **и** ненужна.

Однако... Вряд ли тут можно усмотреть однородные придаточные предложения.

1. Зато очевидно по размаху городского строительства (что очевидно?), ***что основатель династии Флавиев был весьма заинтересован в расположении к нему народных масс.***

Это придаточное подлежащное предложение, распространяющее сказуемое главного предложения. Короче, само придаточное - это подлежащее.

Выходит примерно так: *Это* (Флавий и его заинтересованность) *очевидно.*

***Это очевидно.*** Вот подлежащее и сказуемое.

Применяем этот метод и ко второму гипотетическому придаточному предложению

2. Зато очевидно по размаху городского строительства (что очевидно?), ***что развёрнутое им грандиозное общественное строительство (служит) тому доказательством.***

Что-то тут не выходит придаточного подлежащного к слову "очевидно". Это предложение, мне кажется, всё таки по смыслу относится к придаточному подлежащному (находится с ним в отношениях сочинения), поскольку *"развёрнутое им грандиозное общественное строительство (служит) тому доказательством"* - это как раз таки доказательство того, что *"полководец Веспасиан был весьма заинтересован в расположении к нему народных масс",* а не того, что что-то там "очевидно".

Далее, выходит в целом так:

> *Это* (Флавий и его заинтересованность) *очевидно, и развёрнутое им грандиозное общественное строительство (служит) тому доказательством.*

Иными словами, второе предложения (*и развёрнутое им грандиозное общественное строительство (служит) тому доказательством*), — скорее всего, находится в отношениях сочинения с предшествующим предложением, а не подчинения с предложением со словом "очевидно".

***Вот финальный вердикт:***

*Зато очевидно по размаху городского строительства, что основатель династии Флавиев (69–96), скромный по своему происхождению полководец Веспасиан, был весьма заинтересован в расположении к нему народных масс, и развёрнутое им грандиозное общественное строительство тому доказательством.*

Answer (score 3):

Запятая нужна - поскольку утверждение в этом месте завершается, а далее идёт аргументация в его пользу (эта часть могла быть и самостоятельным предложением). Не хватает сказуемого "является" (творительный падеж повис в воздухе), без него нужно тире и более естественен именительный падеж (- тому доказательство).